# QGIS 3.22 LTR on OSX 12.5 installation in 2022 post KyngChaos

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

I'm aiming to install the most compatible QGIS version and supporting packages with my OSX 12.5 system in 2022.

My last setup used the KyngChaos package 3.16, however a perusal of the  website shows they've quit packaging QGIS. It points to using the package from QGIS official repo.

Does anyone have any experience with installing QGIS 3.22 LTR on OSX 12.5? Is there any pre/post installation requirements that anyone knows of?

Comment: This official [dmg](https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-pr.dmg) doesn't work?

Comment: I was assuming it works, but wondering if there were any known issues, incompatibilties etc.
I've installed it (QGIS 3.22 LTR) and hit inevitable issues, no plugins I've tried to install will load properly, probably due to python version compatiblity (my pythons a bit rusty). I'll have a peruse and see if I can resolve; if I can't find anything I'll ask here in a seperate—more specific—post.

Comment: Normally QGIS comes with its own embedded Python libraries, e.g. on Ubuntu at: `/usr/share/qgis/python`. The best you can do is, if you have any error messages (and I hope you do), share them here so people can help debug this.